# Why does Spring @Scheduled not work with @Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am using Spring Boot and Scheduling.

In Spring, why does this work properly (the method gets called every 5 seconds) -

```
//@Bean
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void foo() {
     System.out.println("bar");
}
```

But this does not (the method does not get called every 5 seconds) -

```
@Bean
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void foo() {
     System.out.println("bar");
}
```

Comment: Strange question ! Why would you like to do that ?? A Spring bean is by default a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

The `@Bean` annotation is used to define bean instances and must return a result. The `@Scheduled` annotation belongs on a *bean method*, not the bean itself, and that method must return void. Also, don't forget to enable scheduling by putting `@EnableScheduling` on one of your `@Configuration` classes.  For example:

**MyConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyConfig
{
}
```

**MyScheduledJob.java**

```
@Component
public class MyScheduledJob
{
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void doSomething() // Note: Should only return void
    {
        System.out.println(Instant.now() + ": MyScheduledJob.doSomething() invoked.");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2017-01-28T03:08:04.760Z:  MyScheduledJob.doSomething() invoked.
2017-01-28T03:08:09.756Z:  MyScheduledJob.doSomething() invoked.
2017-01-28T03:08:14.755Z:  MyScheduledJob.doSomething() invoked.
2017-01-28T03:08:19.758Z:  MyScheduledJob.doSomething() invoked.
```

Answer (score 2):

A `@Bean` annotation is used for Java-based configuration to annotate a method, that constructs a bean. It's just wrong annotation and should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

The two annotations that you are putting on that method do not make much sense to put together.

@Bean is used to create a singleton for autowiring depdencies across your application. http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

@Scheduled is used for scheduling tasks for rerunning. 

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

The reason that this does not make sense is that, generally, your Beans are created at application startup and autowired into their dependencies (done once).  In contrast, Schedule implies that you would want this to happen on a regular cadence.